# rspec nil class error in controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a profile model with `avatar` attr and `full_name` method that uses `first_name` and `last_name` attrs. All of these are delegated in user model. I don't really understand how I can get the nil class error. If I delete the image tag line the tests pass, so user can't be nil since I also call `user.full_name`. I also have other models where I use the `avatar` and `full_name` and the specs are working fine there. It works in dev env too.

What did I miss here?

error for all the 3 it blocks:

```
Failure/Error: <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small_thumb), class: "profile-index-avatar" %>

ActionView::Template::Error:
  undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass
  Did you mean?  URI
```

show.html.erb

```
<% @product.users.each_slice(2) do |user_row| %>
  <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
    <% user_row.each do |user| %>
      <%= link_to user_profile_path(user) do %>
        <div class="col-md-6 product-user-column">
          <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small_thumb), class: "profile-index-avatar" %>
          <%= user.full_name %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

controller spec

```
describe "GET show" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:product) { create(:product, :product_with_nested_attrs) }
  let!(:product_user) { create(:product_user, user: @user, product: product, role: "owner") }
  before(:each) do
    get :show, id: product
  end

  it "assigns products" do
    expect(assigns(:product)).to eq(product)
    expect(assigns(:product).industry_products.size).to eq(1)
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :show }
end
```

UPDATE

Based on zetetic's suggestions I checked if avatar is nil. The user avatar is not nil for the index action neither the avatar for the show action.

If put the "avatar not nil for show" method in while show page contains image tag then it raises the same error just like for the rest. If I delete the image tag line then it says it's not nil.

```
describe "GET index" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:product) { create(:product, :product_with_nested_attrs) }
  before(:each) do
    get :index
  end

  it "avatar not nil for show" do
    expect(@user.avatar).to_not be_nil
  end

  it "assigns products" do
    expect(assigns(:products)).to eq([product])
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :index }
end

describe "GET show" do
  let!(:profile) { create(:profile, user: @user) }
  let!(:product_user) { create(:product_user, user: @user, product: product, role: "owner") }
  let!(:product) { create(:product, :product_with_nested_attrs) }
  before(:each) do
    get :show, id: product
  end

  it "avatar not nil for show" do
    expect(@user.avatar).to_not be_nil
  end

  it "assigns products" do
    expect(assigns(:product)).to eq(product)
    expect(assigns(:product).industry_products.size).to eq(1)
  end

  it { is_expected.to respond_with 200 }
  it { is_expected.to render_template :show }
end
```

Comment: Is there a value for `@user`? Do the factories raise errors if the user is missing?

Comment: zetetic, `@user` is used for all the actions (index, destroy, etc.). So it's working fine (28 examples and 3 failures). And as I wrote if I take out the line with image tag it passes with `user.full_name`. All the specs passed before I decided to put image tag in as well.

Comment: I would look closely at the factories and/or models to make sure they are returning the values you expect. It often helps to add additional expectations temporarily to make sure the values are really there (e.g `expect(@user.avatar).to_not be_nil`)

Comment: zetetic, I will update my question in 3 mins, pls take a look at it. I found something weird.

Answer (score 1):

avatar is nil for one of the users

Comment: JaTo, I guess only in test env. If so, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: check that your user factory creates an avatar. Also check that the avatar responds to url

Comment: JaTo, factory seems to be working fine. Pls check out my update. If I take out the image tag from the view then it says avatar is not nil.